# This suggestion still needs 1 approval vote from other reviewers. But I have edit rights?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was reviewing a edit from a 600 rep user, and found it good to approve.
However when I approved it I got the message "This suggestion still needs 1 approval vote from other reviewers" while I have 3700 rep and thus could edit the question myself and so renders the need for one more approval useless.
To me this seems like a bug?

related question: [scrollable floaty image in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482130/scrollable-floaty-image-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is intentional. See the special Stack Overflow rules in [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

Comment: Seems like a strange design choice, I feel they should take into account the rep of the user that approves the edit.